# finding bitrate of videos using ffmpeg

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

I have some mp4 videos in a folder and I need to find the bitrate of each file and save them in a file. I have this cmandline code:

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} sh -c " echo -n '{} ' && ffmpeg -i '{}' 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*bitrate: //p' " > result.txt
```

but I am working in windows and it produces this error:

```
'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

do you know what is the equivalent command code in windows?

Comment: The `cmd` tag is for Microsoft Windows cmd.exe issues.

Comment: @lit Which is exactly the reason why I added it. I have no idea why you removed it.

Comment: @Reino, oh, so is your question a request for someone to convert the UNIX shell (bash, ksh, etc.) command into a Windows cmd.exe command?

Comment: @lit It's not my question, but that's what OP is asking, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ffprobe (included with ffmpeg), use the following command:

```
ffprobe -v error -print_format json -show_entries stream=bit_rate input.mp4>output.json
```

This will put the output into a json file and put the bitrate of all streams of the file. These are usually the bitrates for video and audio, but would also show bitrates of subtitle tracks and possibly other audio tracks.

Comment: is it a way to save the bitrate in a variable? or txt file

Comment: @david, yes it is, in my example above, you get it as a json file, which is basically a structured list of variables. That would contain the bitrates of every video stream.

If you use this command:
ffprobe -i input.mp4 -v 0 -show_entries format=bit_rate -of compact=p=0:nk=1 >bitrate.txt

This will put exactly the total bitrate into the textfile called bitrate.txt, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: You can store the result of `ffprobe` in a shell variable:
1) store command arguments for ffprobe query in array: bitrate for video -> 
`command_video_bitrate=(ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "${i}")`
2) execute command in array and store result in variable -> 
`result_video_bitrate=$("${command_video_bitrate[@]}")`
3) Retrieve the value -> `echo  ${result_video_bitrate}`

Comment: Not all formats will report stream bitrates, such as Matroska (`.mkv`).

Comment: .webm is also no reporting bitrate to me :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you've found that command-line, but it's a Linux Bash command-line, which obviously won't work on Windows CMD.

You need to use a FOR-loop to iterate over all your mkv-files. And to extract specific format- or stream information I'd suggest you use [ffprobe](/questions/tagged/ffprobe), which is specifically designed for such a task.

```
FOR %A IN (*.mkv) DO @ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format=bit_rate -of default=nk=1:nw=1 "%A"
```

To save the output to a file, simply redirect it to a file with parentheses around the command: `(FOR ... "%A") > result.txt`